# How come when my uilabel text is shrunken the text inside is no longer centered?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

As shown in my picture, when the text in my UILabel starts to shrink, it starts to move farther down below the centre. How can I make sure it stays in the centre no matter if it gets shrunken or not?

**Picture of problem (Bradford West Gwillimbury it is very noticeable):**

[image]

**Code:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    else
        [[cell.contentView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];



    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (20, 0, self.view.frame.size.width-20, 90)];
    UILabel *cityLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (10, 5, self.view.frame.size.width-20, 55)];
    UILabel *supportedCitiesLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (10, 65, self.view.frame.size.width-20, 20)];

    cityLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:50.0];
    cityLabel.text = mainCities[indexPath.row];
    supportedCitiesLabel.text = partCities[indexPath.row];

    if([supportedCitiesLabel.text isEqualToString:@""]) // city has no supported cities so centering main city in view
    {
        supportedCitiesLabel.hidden = true;
        [cityLabel setFrame:CGRectMake (10, 5, self.view.frame.size.width-20, 55+25)];
    }


    cityLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;




    CGRect labelRect = cityLabel.frame;
    cityLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    cityLabel.numberOfLines = 1;

    CGFloat fontSize = 50;
    while(fontSize > 0.0)
    {
        NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc]init];
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        NSDictionary *attrDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize], NSFontAttributeName, paragraphStyle, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil];

        CGSize size = [cityLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(labelRect.size.width, 10000)
                                                                options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine|NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                             attributes:attrDict context:nil].size;

        if(size.height <= labelRect.size.height)
            break;

        fontSize -= 1.0;
    }

    cityLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize];
    [cityLabel setBaselineAdjustment:UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters];


    [cityLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [supportedCitiesLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];



    [view addSubview:cityLabel];
    [view addSubview:supportedCitiesLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:view];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];



    return cell;
}
```

**Here is result when I set cityLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth to NO instead of YES:**
[image]

Comment: can you add code of - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method

Comment: Hey rishi. It is "return 90;"... I have the same height for all rows.

Comment: If you are doing yourself the `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` (if I understood correctly my quick look, it's your `while` loop), put it to `FALSE`, this way setting `baselineAdjustment` property of `UILabel` will work (as it's said by the doc, `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` will ignore the `baselineAdjustment` setting.

Comment: @Larme doing so does centre the text vertically. However now it cuts off some of the text (such as in the case of "Bradford West Gwillimbury"): http://i58.tinypic.com/6oo6dw.png

Comment: @Larme I do not think that setting baselineAdjustment to centre is required if setting adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth to NO. The results appear the same with or without setting it to centre so correct me if i'm wrong but maybe the default is centre?

Comment: Added the picture to original post.

Comment: The issue is that the calculation for the size is wrong. In other words, either the width calculated is wrong, either the width parameter is wrong. Could you log the values? Look at the doc of `baselineAdjustment` that's why you need to set the `adjustFontSizeToFit` to no.

Comment: I am not sure how to fix the miscalculated size. Here is for Bradford West Gwillimbury: font size = 33.000000... labelRect width = 300.000000